# `inotify` notifies only the first change in a file

Tags: linux, file, inotify

I would like to write a simple C program that detects changes in a regular file. I decided to use `inotify`. The problem is that my program detects only the first change in a file.
This is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define EVENT_SIZE  (sizeof(struct inotify_event))
#define BUF_LEN     (1024*(EVENT_SIZE + 16))


int main()
{
    int length, i = 0;
    int fd;
    int wd;
    char buffer[BUF_LEN];

    fd = inotify_init();

    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("inotify_init");
    }

    wd = inotify_add_watch(fd, "/path/to/my/file.txt", IN_MODIFY);

    while(1)
    {
        length = read(fd, buffer, BUF_LEN);
        if (length < 0) {
            perror("read");
        }  
        
        while (i < length) {
            struct inotify_event* event = (struct inotify_event*) &buffer[i];
            if (event->len) {
                if (event->mask & IN_MODIFY) {
                        printf("The file %s was modified.\n", event->name);
                }
            }
            i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
        }
    }
    inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

`read()` returns 0 so my program never goes out from `while(i<length){}`. When I commented out this loop it seems that `read()` returns any value only with the first change in a file and next it waits forever.

Do you have any idea why I cannot detects changes in the file? Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT** I checked cli version of inotify and it also doesn't work as expected. I called `inotifywait -m file.txt` and it says that my file has been deleted but the only change I had made was adding some letters to it and save. Here is a full output of the command:

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
file.txt OPEN 
file.txt CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE 
file.txt ATTRIB 
file.txt DELETE_SELF
```

Comment: *my file has been deleted but the only change I had made was adding some letters to it and save.*  How do you know your editor didn't delete the file?

Comment: I still have the file on a disk, can open and edit it.

Comment: What evidence do you have that it's the *same* file?

Comment: Same name, same location. Could it be that this file is deleted after each save? This is very strange to me. What then should I do to be able to use `inotify`?

Comment: Run `ls -i` (lower-case letter "i") against the file and see if the inode number changes.  Note that if the inode number stays the same, that doesn't mean your editor didn't delete the file anyway - it just means a new file with the same name may have received the same inode number.  If that is happening, you'll have to put an inotify watch on the directory and watch for file creations and track those, too.  But that's subject to race conditions and will miss events.

Comment: The inode numer has been changed. Thanks @AndrewHenle for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For one, you're not resetting `i` within the loop, so the first time it gets increased to `EVENT_SIZE`, subsequent reads of length `EVENT_SIZE` will not be looked at.

Also, you're checking if the length of the filename, `event->len` is nonzero, but at least the man page says that:

> The  name  field  is  present only when an event is returned for a file inside a watched directory; it identifies the filename within to the watched directory.

so it will not be filled when you're watching only an individual file.

If you fix it to reset `i`; and watch the whole directory, or don't look at `event->name`, then it works.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the errors. I have already corrected them. However, I still have the problem that after the first change in the file, the program stops at `read()`.  Out of curiosity I checked how the console version of inotify would work, I called `inotifywait -m file.txt` and it turned out that it doesn't work as expected either. I added the console result to the question.

Comment: @userr019283, well, your run with `inotifywait` shows that the file wasn't modified, but deleted. Probably replaced by another file being renamed on top. There's your problem.